# Issues compiling GnuPG: ./configure: command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, gpg

I wanted to install [GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org) by compiling the binaries but I'm stuck on the second dependancy, libgpg-error. I'll check the obvious tomorrow and shasum the tarball, re-download it (etc) but I'm hoping I can find a little insight into what's going on here. I'm on macOS Catalina.

Here's what I'm trying to do in Terminal (as is documented in the README). Briefly, configure, make, install:

```
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo make clean
```

However, the first command *sudo ./configure* produces an error:

```
sudo: ./configure: command not found
```

So,

1. I'm wondering if anybody has experienced the same issue and why? Is this common?
2. Should I expect more issues compiling GnuPG from the binaries?
3. Any suggestions on alternative PGP command line tools?

I am not interested in the GPGTools/PGP Suite for macOS. I don't want all the bels and whistles. I'm just looking for a command line PGP utility.

**Edit:** Revised question with Terminal input and output.

Comment: Are you in the correct directory when running `sudo ./configure`? Is `configure` executable? Also, usually the only step which requires `sudo` is `make install`, configuring and compiling should work with without.

Comment: This edit has significantly changed the issue.  What was the ex ct commands you used and what does the re dme say

Comment: . @timd I don't know how much do the readme & this site https://macgpg.sourceforge.io/docs/howto-build-gpg-osx.txt.asc differ, but it's a good idea to give it a go. this page points to the former link: https://www.gnupg.org/download/supported_systems.html

Comment: @nohillside thanks, i chmod u+x configure and that solved the issue.

Comment: @ankii I saw that guide when you posted it earlier but it uses gunpg 1.4

Comment: @TimD post an answer then! :) I made title more clear in case someone comes searching for it. All other users who downloaded will see same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue *command not found* occurs because the script *./configure* is not executable. I fixed it by setting the executable bit for the user with chmod.

While in the root directory, type the command in Terminal:

```
chmod u+x configure
```

Comment: Interesting. I just downloaded the tar ball from gnupg.org, the extracted `configure` script is executable. Did you extract the tar ball in a special way (e.g. with `sudo`)?

Comment: I double clicked the archive in Finder but I did that with the ntph binary too

Comment: Do you have a special unarchiver installed or are you using the standard Archive Utility? Access rights are set within the tar file already (and there they are correctly set to +x) so I wonder whether an extraction utility does something strange here.

Comment: No, default Catalina 10.15.5. I should see if I can replicate the issue tomorrow

Comment: If the problem is reproducible in Finder can you also run `tar tvzf gnupg-2.2.20.tar.bz2 | grep configure` to check the permissions within the file, and use `tar xvzf gnupg-2.2.20.tar.bz2` to see whether it also happens then?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I re-downloaded the tarball and extracted it from Finder. I couldn't reproduce the problem and was able to run ./configure successfully. The only thing I did differently this time was verify  the SHA sum.